# UIToolbar as inputAccessoryView hides labels during push/pop animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, inputaccessoryview

I have a `UIViewController` inside a `UINavigationController`. The `UIViewController` class overrides `-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder` and `-(UIView *)inputAccessoryView`, such that it has a `UIToolbar` docked at the bottom. This `UIToolbar` has a `UILabel` as a subview. I should mention that both are fully wired up programmatically using auto layout. Now when the view controller is pushed onto the navigation stack, the label is not visible during the push animation. Only after the push animation has finished, the label suddenly appears on the tool bar docked at the bottom. The exact same thing happens when the navigation stack pops back to this view controller. What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Could you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you programmatically creating your constraints? I had a similar issue where the UILabel wasn't appearing at all, and I switched my constraints to use the Visual Format Language and it magically worked.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work.. How and where are you setting up your inputAccessoryView? As a lazy getter?

Comment: I subclass `UIToolbar` as my inputAcessoryView and subclass `UICollectionView`, which returns the toolbar as the accessory view. This was really helpful for me http://derpturkey.com/uitextfield-docked-like-ios-messenger/